Why does the iframe content not display on other screen dimensions?
What I'm trying to do is : extract pages one by one from a pdf Document and create an url using blob to put it in the src parameter of my Iframe. It works perfectly until I use Chrome DevTool to see if the iframe displays correctly on other devices. Everytime I load the iframe, I get "Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode" as an issue in the browser.
I did some research to fix this. First, the error "Quirks Mode" means I have to write  at the beginning of my file. The problem is: I use Next.js, so it's supposed to be automatically fixed. Indeed, the iframe displays the document correctly on other devices if I use the original url that contains the entire pdf document. So I figured that the problem would be the url and not the iframe, but the blob url (page by page) works without using Chrome DevTool(normal desktop dimension) so I'm stuck in this vicious circle. I also tried to comment every scss effect on my React component and it still does the error so it isn't a css error. I'm pretty sure the problem comes from building the document within the iframe using the url, but I'm probably wrong because I can't fix this error.
EDIT : pdfUrl is a AWS bucket url, pageUrl is a blob url
const newPages: string[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sourceDoc.getPageCount(); i++) {
      const [page] = await pdfDoc.copyPages(sourceDoc, [i]);
      pdfDoc.addPage(page);
      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
      const blob = new Blob([pdfBytes], { type: "application/pdf" });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      newPages.push(url);
      pdfDoc.removePage(0);
    }
    setPages(newPages);

<iframe
  src={pdfUrl + `#toolbar=0&view=FitH`}   //Works everywhere
/>

<iframe
  src={pageUrl + `#toolbar=0&view=FitH`}   //Works on desktop (Quirks Mode issue on other devices)
/>



Please show some code and provide a link to a working example.

@DavidBradshaw I added some code, but I'm not sure how you want me to provide a link. The mobile view just displays the empty iframe. If you want screenshots, I can upload some.

@KJ In conclusion, the Iframe displays on mobile devices since the beginning, but I could not test it. (someone else did) However, it displays incorrectly because, indeed, view=FitH does not work on safari, but it doesn't solve the issue where my iframe is not displayed on my Chrome DevTools in a different dimension. I will keep this question opened in case someone knows why. Thank you! :)

@KJ So you mean that my browser force a zoom factor on the iframe when I put the mobile dimensions? Because even without the view=FitH, it does not display the document page by page, it's empty. However, on a true mobile device, it displays something, but the FitH was destroying the look of it. By removing the parameter from the url, the iframe on a true mobile device is displayed without fitting, but it's more viable. The browser issue remains (iframe empty without a conflict of zoom factor because view=FitH is removed).
